# Can't stream mp4 using osmf, it only downloads the whole file and then plays it

Tags: flash, video-streaming, mp4, osmf, m4v

I'm using osmf and I'm tring to stream over http a m4v file (osmf should support it)
Instead of streaming it, it downloads the whole file and when it's done, it plays it.
How can I make it stream it instead of downloading it?

My code is:

```
var resource:URLResource = new URLResource("http://path/to/file.m4v");
mediaFactory = new DefaultMediaFactory();
var element:MediaElement = mediaFactory.createMediaElement(resource);
player = new MediaPlayer(element);
container = new MediaContainer();
container.addMediaElement(element);
videoContainer.addChild(container);
```

I have tried instead of using the mediaFactory:

```
var videoElement:VideoElement =  new VideoElement(resource ,new HTTPStreamingNetLoader());
```

No success.

Comment: How are you generating your m4v file? If it is a elementary mpeg4 file then it is not streamable.

Answer (score 0):

To make mp4's playable immediately you need to hint it. Use MP4Box.

```
MP4Box -hint input_file
```

Google a bit about hinting to understand it better. The idea is that the header is put at the begining of the file.